# Añadir imagen a iTextSharp desde resources

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy creando un .pdf con un reporte y necesito meterle una imagen, encontré este código y funciona:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("localización de la imagen");
imagen.BorderWidth = 0;
imagen.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
float percentage = 0.0f;
percentage = 150 / imagen.Width;
imagen.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
```

El problema es que, en vez de usar la localización de la imagen, me parece más cómodo usar una imagen desde los recursos del proyecto, ya que al ser usado en varios computadores, me tocaría cambiarle la ruta en cada uno.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que te sirva ahora pero esto sera de ayuda para quienes tenga la duda en un futuro. Encontré la solución a la incógnita en un blog y a mi me funciono de esta manera.

```
                // Creamos la imagen y le ajustamos el tamaño
                iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Proyecto_FIS.Properties.Resources.Cespt, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                imagen.BorderWidth = 0;
                imagen.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                float percentage = 0.0f;
                percentage = 150 / imagen.Width;
                imagen.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);

                // Insertamos la imagen en el documento
                doc.Add(imagen);
```

Comment: sería bueno colocar la referencia a la fuente original para dar créditos al autor

Answer (score 0):

no se si estás utilizando una Aplicación de Forms, si es el caso podés utilizar este código, el cual te abre un dialogo para seleccionar un archivo desde tu PC.

```
OpenFileDialog dialogo = new OpenFileDialog();  
dialogo.Title = "Seleccionar una imagen";
dialogo.Filter = "png (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";  
dialogo.ShowDialog();  
iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(openFileDialog1.FileName);
imagen.BorderWidth = 0;
imagen.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
float percentage = 0.0f;
percentage = 150 / imagen.Width;
imagen.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
```

En este caso esto debería de funcionarte.